# Is fish skin good for you?

Tags: nutrition, fish, omega-3

It is well documented that eating fish, especially oily fish, is generally very good for us. We know that fish flesh is very high in lean protein and various vitamins and minerals, as well as omega 3.

We know that fish bones are high in calcium.

All this means that small, oily fish like sardines and pilchards are a win/win. But being small, it is tedious to skin them, and indeed it is quite normal to leave the skin on, and indeed quite often the scales are still on.

So apart from avoiding the tedium of skinning such small fish, is there any particular nutritional benefit to eating fish skin?